# how to get html table td attribute unique id with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, show-hide

hi guys I'm trying go create tool tip for every `HTML table cell` do you guys have any idea how can i get `td` attribute id here

thanks a lot 
jquery code sample

```
   $(function () {
    $(".test").hover(
        function () {

                        var toolTipHtml = $("#ToolTipDiv").clone();

            $(this).append(toolTipHtml);
            toolTipHtml.show("slow");
        },
        function () {
            var toolTipHtml = $(this).find(".tooltip");

            toolTipHtml.hide();
            toolTipHtml.remove();
        }
    );

});

 echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
      $id = $row['id_out_org'];
           echo "<tr>";  
         echo "<td>" .$row['KG']."</td>";        
        echo "<td class='test'>" .$row['B']."</td>";
        echo "<td >" .$row['B']."</td>";
        echo  "<td class='test'>"; 
        echo "<div id = 'ToolTipDiv' class='tooltip' style='background-color: White; display: none; width: 20%;'>";

        echo "Total: $ "; echo $totalp = $total + $fuel;

        echo "</div>";
         "</td>";


        echo "</tr>";           
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: how are you activating the tool tip on hoover, onclick,....

Comment: Better you use below open source plug in http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip.
It is fulfill your need.

Answer (score 1):

Use a catch-all selector and then iterate over them:

```
$("td[id$=ToolTipDiv_]").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', 'some tool tip');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you use this open source plug in 
[Tooltip](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip)

It might fulfill your need. 
See examples [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

```
$('#table td.test').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the HTML and ID from every table cell:

```
$('td').each(function() {
  var toolTipHtml = $(this).html(); // now you have the contents of the cell
  id = $(this).attr('id');  // now you have the id
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help when i alert the toolTipHtml its alert all cells i just want to alert only spesific column cell do you have any idea how can i do that

Comment: Yes.. it depends.. For instance if you just want the first one: `$('td:eq(0)')` or if it has a class `$('td.yourclass')` or if it has a specific id `$("td[id$=ToolTipDiv_]")`

Comment: i just edit my code above can you please take a look what i am doing wrong now i just get only first row as a tooltipbox. i m about the cry :((( again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

since you are using a Hoover you may use something like this

```
$('.tooltip').hover(function() {
   alert(this.id);
   // or to get the id of the row
var toolTipHtml = $("#"+this.id).clone();
});
```